# Pattern for LIKE in SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all rows that start with any character.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '[a-z]%' ;
```

The type of rows I would like to find look like this:

```
ID  DATA

993 DEF055900960

994 DEF055900961

995 DEF055900964

996 DEF056102254

997 DEF056131201
```

I have unsucessfully tried RLIKE and REGEXP and also added upper case A-Z ot the pattern.

Why is the following not working?

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[a-z]%' ; and it did not produce any rows either. SAme with RLIKE

Comment: DEF are capital letters and not in the range a-z. Do you use a case-sensitive collation ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field RLIKE '[a-z]' ;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e37da/7)

I went through here to read about [Pattern Matching in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: paste some data of youir table in posted question

Comment: wait , let me try on sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '[^A-Z]%';
```

Comment: The cap ^ character inside character clase [] is use to exclude pattern .

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

For example, assume we have this data set.

```
mysql> select * from a;
+------+
| b    |
+------+
| abc  |
| zxxb |
| kkfy |
| 0002 |
+------+
4 rows in set
```

We want to select everything with the a-z pattern

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM a WHERE b REGEXP BINARY '[a-z]';
+------+
| b    |
+------+
| abc  |
| zxxb |
| kkfy |
+------+
3 rows in set
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/600c4/1)

### For your data set

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2414/2)

Use the regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM a WHERE b REGEXP BINARY '[a-zA-Z0-9]';
+--------------+
| b            |
+--------------+
| DEF055900960 |
| DEF055900961 |
| DEF055900964 |
| DEF056102254 |
| DEF056131201 |
+--------------+
5 rows in set
```

Comment: Thank you! THis works. But do you have an explanation why LIKE '[A-Z]%' does not work?

Comment: In the OP you had lower case pattern `LIKE [a-z]%` and all your data is uppercase - thus no matches. (sorry for the late response, I forgot about answering here)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT `firstname`
FROM `users`
WHERE firstname
REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]'
```

Comment: If you need only rows start from A-Z only then use `REGEXP BINARY '^[A-Z]'`